# How to get a list of topics from a chm file in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, html-helper, chm

I am trying to get list of topics in c#.

Until now I was not able to do it?

Is there a way that I can programatically retrieve all of the topics from a chm file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276019/get-a-list-of-topics-from-a-chm-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: @NileshLanke - This topic might be interesting for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270455/c-sharp-writing-a-chm-viewer

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but none I'm aware of that are you can do with just C#. CHM is a "Compiled HTML" file. Basically, it's a folder full of HTML and some other proprietary format files just compiled into a single file.

One way to get a list of the files, is to decompile it. There are many ways to accomplish this:

1. 7Zip can de-compile .CHM files, it may also let you browse it the same way it lets you browse a ZIP file (I'm not sure on the second option)
2. On Windows systems, the hh.exe utility can be used to decompile CHM files as well. You'll probably need to install the HTML Help Workshop to get this file, but I believe you can distribute it royalty free and it works from the command line.

For example:

```
C:\>HH.EXE -decompile D:/xTemp/decompile-folder C:/MyFolder/MyHelpFile.chm
```

See: http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_command.htm for further details.